# Remove dictionaries with a key with empty strings from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Sorry if this might be very trivial, but for some reason I'm having a hard time accessing the elements of this loaded data structure.

I am using the Google places API in Python for a bunch of locations, so I have a list of places. Essentially, I am trying to remove all the entries that do not have a place_id. This is what my object looks like:

```
[{'candidates': [], 'status': 'ZERO_RESULTS'},
 {'candidates': [{'place_id': 'ChIJ2YPts0rGUIYRHZkmh8TxBT4'}], 'status': 'OK'},
 {'candidates': [], 'status': 'ZERO_RESULTS'},
 {'candidates': [{'place_id': 'ChIJ9_uV17leXIYRgQc7NludRdw'}], 'status': 'OK'},
 {'candidates': [], 'status': 'ZERO_RESULTS'},
 {'candidates': [{'place_id': 'ChIJWVukvUKvw4cRFGFVXGHNX9A'}], 'status': 'OK'},
 {'candidates': [{'place_id': 'ChIJ1VXMS8i_9YgR6NTQL_9BKMs'}], 'status': 'OK'},
 {'candidates': [{'place_id': 'ChIJ79Q4K1YAQIgRe-WjYCw9MuM'}], 'status': 'OK'},
 {'candidates': [{'place_id': 'ChIJ8WoxTJ7qQIYRDZX5JBrofUw'}], 'status': 'OK'},
 {'candidates': [], 'status': 'ZERO_RESULTS'}]
```

I tried doing this:

```
{place_id: v for place_id, v in place_id.items() if v}
```

But I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I understand that the object is a list, but I don't know how to access the dictionary within the list so that I am only selecting the ones with a place_id. Can someone tell me how I can filter the object?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list-comprehension. If `lst` is your list from the question, then:

```py
out = [d for d in lst if any("place_id" in v for v in d["candidates"])]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {
        "candidates": [{"place_id": "ChIJ2YPts0rGUIYRHZkmh8TxBT4"}],
        "status": "OK",
    },
    {
        "candidates": [{"place_id": "ChIJ9_uV17leXIYRgQc7NludRdw"}],
        "status": "OK",
    },
    {
        "candidates": [{"place_id": "ChIJWVukvUKvw4cRFGFVXGHNX9A"}],
        "status": "OK",
    },
    {
        "candidates": [{"place_id": "ChIJ1VXMS8i_9YgR6NTQL_9BKMs"}],
        "status": "OK",
    },
    {
        "candidates": [{"place_id": "ChIJ79Q4K1YAQIgRe-WjYCw9MuM"}],
        "status": "OK",
    },
    {
        "candidates": [{"place_id": "ChIJ8WoxTJ7qQIYRDZX5JBrofUw"}],
        "status": "OK",
    },
]
```

---

EDIT: To get vector of preserved indices + output list, you can do:

```py
preserved_indices, out = map(
    list,
    zip(
        *[
            (idx, d)
            for idx, d in enumerate(lst)
            if any("place_id" in v for v in d["candidates"])
        ]
    ),
)
print(preserved_indices)
print(out)
```

Comment: This seems to work! Thank you, I also need to conserve the index, is there a way to do that without adding another key called index? Or maybe output a vector that gives me the index of each of removed/preserved entries?